# Is the correct way to populate my database in Plesk using their Database tab, SSMS, My Little Admin, or some other way?

Tags: sql-server, plesk, plesk-onyx

I cannot find much in the way of written instructions on how to copy my database to Plesk.

This [page](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/obsidian/quick-start-guide/plesk-tutorial.74376/#step-2-create-a-database) simply says, "*To create a database and a database user: Go to Databases > Add Database.*"

And then it shows a screenshot which does not match what I have; specifically, it shows an "Import Dump" button which I do not have:

[image]

This is what I see in my session (no Import Dump button):

[image]

I zipped a .bak file of my database contents and uploaded it to the File Manager's Files section:

[image]

...but how do I move it from there to the Database area, and what do I then do to populate my tables with the contents of the .bak file?

Is this something that should be done using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, or from "My Little Admin," or what?

I was able to create the (empty) tables by running a script.sql file I generated from my local database. My Little Admin indicates that the empty tables do exist on the server, for example here is the ACTORS table:

[image]

OTOH, SSMS shows that the database exists, but shows no tables:

[image]

Comment: The first dialog you show is for MySQL, not SQL Server. You can tell because it displays phpMyAdmin in the highlighted band. phpMyAdmin is for use only with MySQL. SQL Server doesn't use dumps to import and export data. Contact Plesk support for help. This is a customer service-related question,  not a programming question.

Comment: The first dialog is from their tutorial. But that explains the lack of an "Import Dump" for my SQL Server DB. Thanks.